# How to give Azure AD application access to required permissions using powershell Az module

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, az

I'm trying to rewrite powershell script that creates Azure AD application and assigns permission to it. The script is using AzureAD module, I would like to use new Az module, so I can run it on Linux/MacOS.

Creating a new application is easy (New-AzADApplication) but I have a problem with permissions.

Old script is using this code to assign permissions:

```
#=============Graph Permissions========================
$req = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$acc1 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "df021288-bdef-4463-88db-98f22de89214","Role"

$req.ResourceAccess = $acc1
$req.ResourceAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" #Microsoft Graph   

Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $AppObjectId  -RequiredResourceAccess $req
```

But this will not work on Linux/MacOS. Is there any way to do this? If not from powershell than maybe using some other method? The main goal is to run it from Linux.

Comment: The script you share does not actually grant permissions, is just marks permissions as required. Do you also need to grant the permissions in the tenant?

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret Indeed I need, but this is already solved using admin consent through a URL request - https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/?view=azure-cli-latest) is easy to get started with and best used for Microsoft's cross-platform command-line experience for managing Azure resources  on macOS, Linux, or Windows and run it from the command line.

**Your case**

In your case you could try with Following CLI command for application permission:

> az ad app permission add --api
>                            --api-permissions
>                            --id
>                            [--subscription]

**For example**

See add a Graph API permission of "[Sign in and read user profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app/permission?view=azure-cli-latest#examples)" command below:

```
az ad app permission add --id eeba0b46-78e5-4a1a-a1aa-cafe6c123456 --api 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 --api-permissions 311a71cc-e848-46a1-bdf8-97ff7156d8e6=Scope
```

**Required Parameters**

Following parameters required for this [permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app/permission?view=azure-cli-latest#required-parameters)

> --api
>
> The target API to access.
>
> --api-permissions
>
> Space seperated list of =.
>
> --id
>
> Identifier uri, application id, or object id.

For more details CLI command you also could refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app/permission?view=azure-cli-latest)

> **Note :**
>
> To executes above command you must need to install the CLI locally,
>   run it in the browser with Azure Cloud Shell, or run in a Docker
>   container. For installation reference you could see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest)

## Powershell Command

You could find details [steps here](https://rajanieshkaushikk.com/2019/07/31/how-to-assign-permissions-to-azure-ad-app-by-using-powershell/)

I hope this would be helpful what you expected to do. Let's try it out. Thank you!

Comment: @paulpb According to your case you can try it out. Let me know if you have any more query regarding your problem.

Comment: Hi, your answer was very helpful. Docker with Azure Cloud Shell looks like the best solution. I'm going to try it right now!

Comment: I did, but due to my low reputation, my votes are not displayed.

Comment: This answer is copy-pasted from the API reference. But what's still missing is where to find the guid (311a71cc...) mapping to "Sign in and read user profile"?

Comment: @Nikolai Koudelia Right you are, We always try to refer our official document towards the user as I also specified the API reference here. What happens usually, sometimes its tough to find  exact resource when need if the document has the exact fix its better to refer them I did the same. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron When I try to use your example `az ad app permission add --id [my ID here] --api 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 --api-permissions 311a71cc-e848-46a1-bdf8-97ff7156d8e6=Scope`, it returns `Updates to converged applications are not allowed in this version.`

Any idea what's going on here? I still can't figure out how to add permissions via the command line.

Comment: @EricHansen What role are you belong to or your tenant has this permission to execute?

Comment: For the error “Updates to converged applications are not allowed in this version”, I did a test in my environment but cannot reproduce the error. It seems related to the application type. Could you please share more information about how did you created the app? Did you add it from App registration ? Is this a  custom-developed application ?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron It's in my personal account. I'm the supreme overlord. I created the app registration in the portal. The app registration is as simple as possible. I simply gave it a name and created it.

Comment: So this is not possible with Az PowerShell, as OP requested?

Comment: Hello I have updated the answer. Please have look and let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @NikolaiKoudelia I know it is late for you but others like me might find my answer useful. I was also looking how to find guid mappings. They can be get with the command `az ad sp show --id <resource-appId>`. For example Azure Active Directory Graph: `az ad sp show --id 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000`.
Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app/permission?view=azure-cli-latest#az_ad_app_permission_add